# Spring Boot Jersey App Error in Tomcat 8.5 AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

When i am running spring boot jersey app on STS IDE as spring boot app. It runs without issues.

[IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1qcT.png)

However when i deploy the app as WAR on tomcat 8.5,I get below error

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12rrd.png)

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:166)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
```

I found some answers on stackoverflow, they refer to to JAX-RS 2.0 method being called with jersey 1.* dependency. I tried to fix this by excluding pom.xml dependencies referring to jersey 1.*. This didn't work.I am not sure what else to do.

POM below

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-cors</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.1</version>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Classes below

[class1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIXMR.png)
[class2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xJS5.png)

Comment: Why don't you post the _useful_ part of the exception that you have in the image, instead of the _useless_ part that you posted?

Comment: In my experience, this error with the UriBuilder will occur when you have code that is trying to use 1.x, but you are forcing it to use 2.x. This is what you are doing with `cxf-rt-rs-security-cors`. Use a different library for what ever you need that one for.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSamsotha you were right. I upgraded the version of that component on pom.xml and now the error 500 went away. However, now i am getting error 404(I am checking this.). But my question still remains, why did it work on my IDE but on tomcat 8.5 it breaks? 
                                                                                                      
                  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-cors</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.15</version>   
  </dependency>

Comment: @PaulSamsotha what did you mean by the useful part of the exception?

Comment: I fixed the 404 error as well.I had to move the @Path("/api") annotation above @RestController. I feel so dumb now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ref comment by Paul Samsotha.

In my case the cxf-rt-rs-security-cors version 2.6.1 dependency was forcing my app into jersey 1.x. I fixed this by simply removing the dependency from pom as I didn't need it.

However, I am not sure why this exception only occurs on tomcat 8.5 and not on STS IDE embedded server.

Thank you Paul Samsotha :)